# Improving credit card like image scan for OCR

Tags: image-processing, filters, morphological-operations, ocr, enhancement

OCR works best for black on white or binary images, where letters have sharp contours, no noise, and solid filling, i.e. they are nothing like this:

[image: part of a document number]

For the curious it's a part of a document number that is embossed.
Applying unsharp mask, thresholding, closing and median operations already improves it a bit, but it still cannot be processed properly by OCR.

[image]

What other operations could bring the image to the preferable state like this manually edited one:

[image]

Comment: aren't you answering your own question? *What did **you** do to achieve that third image?*

Comment: Like I said I manually edited the image with GIMP

Comment: but *what* did you do in GIMP?

Comment: bucket fill and erase tool on the image in the middle. The operations to get the middle image are mentioned in the question.

Comment: soooooo what about implementing "bucket fill" to.. fill the outer areas with black, then bucket fill on all areas "touching" the black with green? Then, just select "green"? It's what you've done before, but automatedly. You already work like an algorithm! You just need to learn to write that algorithm down.